# PowerShell: how to get rid output lines in recursive data searches

Tags: powershell

I have 100 .sql files and I would like to check whether the String `"Das ist ein Test"` is included in this files.

So far I have found only the `Select-String` cmdlet. This gives me, however, only the files in which the String is found.

Here my PowerhShell script:

```
$path = "F:\Masterarbeit\Daten\"
$search = "Das ist ein Test"

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.sql -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $search -casesensitive | select FileName

exit
```

And this is the output I get:

[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgpCE.png)

How can I now change my code so that I only get the file name where the string is not contained at all? I also know that there is a paramater called `-NotMatch`, but unfortunately it returns only all lines where the string is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are doing a check on every single line of every file. What you want is to do a check on every file (if it contains the string).

```
$path = "F:\Masterarbeit\Daten"
$search = "Das ist ein Test"

# loop through all files
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.sql -Recurse) {
    # get all lines from the current file containing the test string 
    $test = Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String $search
    # are there any?
    if ($test) {
        # then skip this one
        continue
    }
    # otherwise print the file name
    $file
}
```

Comment: ah okay, thanks for the tip, but now I get an error message, that the path can not be found --> For example: `Get-Content: The path "C:\Windows\system32\Daten_1.sql" can not be found, because it does not exist + $test = Get-Content $file | Select-String $search`. I'm a little bit confused about the error message.

Comment: Apparently $file alone doesn't return the full path. I had to add `.FullName` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would take what you have and wrap the `Select-String` in a `Where-object` block with the `-not` operator.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.sql -Recurse |
#Only keep files that don't return a match
Where-Object { -not (Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern $search -casesensitive) } |
Select-Object Name
```